# Print numbers 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, …, 3 using while/do while

Tags: java, while-loop

I want to print numbers in the range of 0 to 3 like this:

> 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, …, 3

but when I'm using this code:

```
    double i = 0;
    while (i <= 3) {
        System.out.printf("%.1f, ", i);
        i+= 0.1;
    }
```

or this:

```
    double j = 0;
    do {
        System.out.printf("%.1f, ", j);
        j+= 0.1;
    } while (j <= 3);
```

i get

> 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, …, **2.9**

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like you may need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please [edit] your question to be more specific with what help you need.

Comment: I changed double to float and now everything works fine. Thank you.

Comment: @JoeC The debugger might not reveal much more than a simple `System.out.println(i)`. It will not explain why the result will be `3.0000000000000013` at some point, and how this problem can be handled.

Comment: @BEN1EK Even if you didn't need it on this problem, Joe's advice will make you a better programmer, period. Every good programmer knows how to properly debug code, and the tools used to debug are some of the most important in a developer's toolkit.

Comment: @corsiKa *"Every good programmer knows how to properly debug code"* - and every *great* programmer does *not* know it 8-D. Seriously, the question could need a hint to another (beginner-level) Q/A about floating point inaccuracies...

Comment: Of course, I read Joe's article and it's very useful.

Comment: @Marco13 sure, I can get on board with that. Ben was able to fix it by changing double to float, but I bet he doesn't understand why. (Hint: Ben: floats and doubles can't store numbers like `0.1` exactly. They can do `.5, .25, .125, .0625...` etc really well though. Hopefully that points you to the right reasons why this happens.

Comment: @corsiKa Thanks. I changed my code to: `int i = 0;
while (i <= 30) {
    System.out.printf("%.1f, ", i * 0.1);
 i++;`
}

Answer (score -1):

It is because of the precision of double. Another solution could be to use a data type that is precise enough, i.e. BigDecimal

```
BigDecimal i = BigDecimal.ZERO;
while (i.compareTo(BigDecimal.valueOf(3)) <= 0) {
    System.out.printf("%.1f, ", i.doubleValue());
    i = i.add(BigDecimal.valueOf(0.1));
}
```